# Jenkins- How to invoke gradle script tasks in different directory than the project root

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

### Project Structure.

> Root/
> -------Android Project/
> ----------------------------ProjectRoot
> -------Other Folders

My git repo contains Root. Inside root i have my android project.

Now when integrating Jenkins freestyle pipeline,
for wrapper location i simply pass ${workspace}/Android Project where my wrapper actually lies.
[image]
But the problem is when i add my tasks: i.e clean | build | assembleDebug its actually running on the Root folder and not inside "Android Project".

i tried "cd Android Project" before running the script but it does not seems to work

Answer (score 1):

i have resolved the issue by simply removing invoke gradle script and adding a shell command window.

Within shell command i cd navigated to the directory i wanted to run the gradle task.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`cd` to the root directory, then call:

```
./gradlw :moduleName:gradleTaskName
```

replace `moduleName` and `gradleTaskName` with your project's real names.

Comment: when i do 
cd ProjectName
./gradlew :app:assembleQaDebug

it says

* What went wrong:
Task 'cd' not found in root project 'Project Root'.

Comment: `cd` is not a `Gradle` task

Comment: ikr, then how can i change the directory?